# Flutter - TextField overflow in custom height

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

In my text view value comes dynamically from the server some times it has one line when the text is big it takes two lines and overflowed the view like the attached picture.

[image: overflow in shops card text view click here to see the problem]

code:

```
  class ShopsCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final UniqueShop uniqueShop;

  ShopsCard({this.uniqueShop});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) =>
                  SearchScreen(
                    searchArguments: SearchArguments(
                        searchType: "campaign_shop_click",
                        campaignShopSlug: uniqueShop.sellerShopSlug,
                        searchDisplayName: uniqueShop.sellerShopBuisnessName),
                  )),
        );
      },
      child: Container(
        height: 144,
        width: 104,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 15.0, top: 10, bottom: 15.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
                height: 95.0,
                width: 104,
                child: uniqueShop.sellerShopImage != null
                    ? populateNetworkImage(imgUrl: uniqueShop.sellerShopImage)
                    : Icon(
                        Icons.image,
                        size: 50,
                      )),
            if (uniqueShop.sellerShopBuisnessName != null)
              Text(
                uniqueShop.sellerShopBuisnessName,
                maxLines: 2,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: commonDmSansTextStyle(
                    fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: darkColor),
              )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is the problem in my code is and how can I solve it!

Comment: did my answer work for you?

Comment: I solved it another way here child widgets exceed the parent container height that's why I got this error. I solved it to reduce bottom padding how much render flex happened. Thanks, brother for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your text with `Expanded` widget or you can use `overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,`

```
 Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  uniqueShop.sellerShopBuisnessName,
                  maxLines: 2,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: commonDmSansTextStyle(
                      fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: darkColor),
                ),
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the maximum line number to one and show an ellipsis if the text overflows

Here is how :

```
Text(
  // ...
  maxLines: 1,
  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
);
```